# Alternative code to read and process array by newline in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, newline

My code is supposed to read a file on the server, store its content in an Array, then read the array elements (eventually each element is a line) and split each line into 7 parts by (:)

I wrote this code and it works 100% fine.

```
lines = File.readlines('/etc/passwd')

lines.each do |line|
line = line.chomp! #I removed the \n
line_arr = line.split(/:/)
puts line_arr.inspect
puts "*************"
end
```

I just want to know if there is a shortcut to do this since each element of the array ends with \n.
Maybe I am a bit confused between a an array elements ending with \n and a string that contains \n

the content of the file looks like this

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
```

As for the output, there's no specific format, because I am going to use this part and extend my code later. As long as I can access those 7 parts that I extracted from the line_arr, i should be fine.

thank you

Comment: Maybe `line_arr = line.chomp!.split(/:/)`?

Comment: Give some sample data.. and output. So that I can code your need.

Comment: post it in the question... not here

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'etc'

[].tap {|ary| Etc.passwd {|u| 
  ary << [u.name, u.passwd, u.uid, u.gid, u.gecos, u.dir, u.shell, u.change, 
          u.uclass, u.expire]
}}
```

Rule of thumb: never try to reimplement behavior that [someone else has already written for you](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-passwd). Unless you are really, *really*, **really**, **REALLY** smart.

Actually, now that you have edited your question, I don't even see why you need those arrays in the first place and cannot just use the `Etc.passwd` iterator and `Struct::Passwd` directly.

Comment: Thanks Jörg. This is definitely a very advanced code! I will study your answer and understand it.